# Proving Abel's theorem (exercise from Stein complex analysis book)

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, power-series

[image]

If we use the hint, consider the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^n r^k a_k $and let $B_k = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i$ . Then according to the summation by parts formula:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n r^k a_k = r^n B_n - r B_1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (r^{k+1} - r^k) B_k$$

If we let $r \to 1$ then LHS becomes $B_n - B_1$ and as $n \to \infty$ we obtain $\sum a_n - B_1$, what am I doing wrong here? But, more importantly what confuses me is why do we need summation by parts? Why can't we just apply $r \to 1$ to the sequence of partial sums $\sum^n r^k a_k$ and then let $n \to \infty$? This is what confuses me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_0=0$. If $B_n=\sum_{k=0}^na_n$, then, when $|r|<1$,\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^n&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_nr^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_{n-1}r^n\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_nr^n-r\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_nr^N\\&=(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_nr^n\end{align}(this is what you would get applying summation by parts). So, if $B=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, we have$$B=B(1-r)\frac1{1-r}=(1-r)\sum_{n=1}^\infty Br^n$$and therefore, for each $r\in(-1,1)$,$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^n\right)-B=(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(B_n-B)r^n.$$Now, if $\varepsilon>0$, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|B-B_n|<\frac\varepsilon2$ when $n\geqslant N$ and take $\delta>0$ such that$$r\in(1-\delta,1)\implies\left|(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(B_n-B)r^n\right|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$Then, if $r\in(1-\delta,1)$,\begin{align}\left|\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^n\right)-B\right|&=\left|(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(B_n-B)r^n\right|\\&\leqslant\left|(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(B_n-B)r^n\right|+\left|(1-r)\sum_{n=N}^\infty(B_n-B)r^n\right|\\&<\frac\varepsilon2+(1-r)\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac\varepsilon2r^n\\&<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

You cannot approach this by simply stating that$$\lim_{r\to1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{r\to1}a_nr^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$because, in general, a limit and an infinite sum do not commute. For instance,$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^xn!}=\lim_{x\to\infty}1=1,$$whereas$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^xn!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty0=0.$$

Comment: Great answer Jose! I have tho a question: I m not quite confortable about the existence of such a $\delta$ and why is it necesary in this proof? Thanks!

Comment: Because asserting that $\lim_{r\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ *means* that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$r\in(1-\delta,1)\implies\left|\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Isnt is $|r-1| < \delta $?

Comment: No, because the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n$ may well diverge when $r>1$. That's why, in my previous comment, I wrote $\lim_{r\to1^-}$, instead of $\lim_{r\to1}$.

Comment: Im sorry to pinpoint this, but you have a mistake in the sixth line as $\sum_{n \geq 1} r^n = \dfrac{r}{1-r}$. Do you mean $n \geq 0$ in the index?

Comment: @Theoneandonly What is there to be sorry about? I've eited my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure. The sixth line should be: $n \geq 0$. As the problem have $\geq 1$, this issue is not relevant because taking one term out of the series does not change the convergence/divergence of the series, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: There may be a way to fix your proof though to avoid changing the index sir. For example, we may assume $r \neq 0$ as $r \to 1^-$.

Comment: Also, one last comment, how do you know $\delta$ exist? Can you construct such a $\delta$ explicitly?

Comment: The map $r\mapsto(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(B_n-B)r^n$ is a polynomial map, and therefore it is continuoues. Besides, it maps $1$ into $0$. So, by the definition of continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$|r-1|<\delta\implies\left|(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(B_n-B)r^n\right|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$

Comment: I think I get it now. This is the same as saying that: $\forall x <1$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such taht $1  - \delta < x <. 1 $. and this is always true because $\sup (-1,1) = 1$. Is my reasoning correct sir?

Comment: No. What has the fact that $\sup(-1,1)=1$ to do with this? I proved that$$r\in(1-\delta,1+\delta)\implies\left|(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(B_n-B)rªn\right|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$So, in particular,$$1-\delta<r<1\implies\left|(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(B_n-B)rªn\right|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is proving
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \lim_{r\to1}\sum_{k=1}^n r^ka_k\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\tag1
$$
This is true, but is not what Abel's theorem is claiming, which is:
$$
\lim_{r\to1}\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n r^ka_k\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\tag2
$$
The reason why result (2) is different from (1) is that you are interchanging two limit operations, which is not always legal. To justify (2) you need a more careful argument, like summation by parts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I on the right track? I did apply the summation by parts formula.